# Reproducible error with Winapi.ShlObj.SHGetFolderPath

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.1-berlin, delphi-10.2-tokyo

With this code I get an AV:

```
uses
  Winapi.ShlObj;

function GetUserAppDataPath: string;
var
  ThisPath: PWideChar;
begin
  if Winapi.ShlObj.SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, ThisPath) = S_OK then
    Result := string(ThisPath)
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

[image]

In Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, if I call this function twice, the second time I get an AV.

What causes this error?

I used `PWideChar` because of the Delphi IDE told me so:
[image]

Comment: Why do you always downvote my questions?

Comment: Exactly! Who downvoted this question and why?

Comment: @dummzeuch Maybe it was the same one who deleted my comment under the solution ("Thank you for the solution!") without explanation?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that's because of the lacking research effort. In this case the required research is to press F1 on the function name.

Comment: No, it wasn't the same one. I know this for a fact, since I had your comment removed. The [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is readily available: *"Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you"."* Hard to miss, with being written in **all bold** characters.

Comment: It should be noted that when using `SHGetKnownFolderPath` then `ThisPath` must be of type `PWideChar`.

Comment: @user - Your problem is not the type of the parameter, AAMOF it is the correct type. Your problem is memory allocation, or the lack of it to be precise. You can use PChar if you like, f.i. after a `GetMem(ThisPath, MAX_PATH)`. The answer explains this by quoting the documentation. For the latter function you mention you have the deallocate the memory that the shell allocates after you've finished with it.

Comment: But the documentation does not mention `MAX_PATH` for `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) doesn't mention `MAX_PATH`, because `SHGetKnownFolderPath` does not use a caller-provided, fixed-size buffer. It allocates a sufficiently sized buffer for you (which you are required to release when done).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't following the protocol laid out by the documentation. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) for the final argument says

> A pointer to a null-terminated string of length MAX_PATH which will receive the path.

You need to allocate that buffer and pass its address.

```
function GetUserAppDataPath: string;
var
  ThisPath: array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
begin
  if Winapi.ShlObj.SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, ThisPath) = S_OK then
    Result := ThisPath
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

Comment: I usually use `array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char` just to be sure. If the *string* is of length `MAX_PATH`, one more `Char` is needed for the terminating zero. And even if I interpret that wrongly, one extra `Char` can't hurt.

Comment: @Rudy You have interpreted incorrectly. The code in my answer is sufficient.

Comment: I don't know if that is true. I will keep on using what I have used before.

Comment: @Rudy It's apparent that you don't know that. You said so. I do know it though.

Comment: David: you may be right, you may be wrong. But my way, it doesn't matter.

Comment: The term *"length"* is commonly used to describe the count of characters, not including the null terminator. The term *"size"* is commonly used to represent the size of a buffer, in bytes, including the null terminator. While the MSDN isn't consistent in using those terms, I'd probably play it safe, too.

Comment: @IInspectable: exactly. Had they used the words *buffer* and *size*, I would have had no doubt. But they talk about the *length* of a *string*. Probably David is right, but the wording in the documentation doesn't really back it up.

Comment: FWIW, the sample code seems to suggest that the *buffer* must be of size `MAX_PATH` indeed: `TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];`.

Comment: @David: good for you. I will still keep on using my way, just to be sure.

Comment: @Rudy "FWIW, the sample code seems to suggest that the buffer must be of size MAX_PATH". Not *size*, but *length*. For Unicode the size is twice the length.